# Fit raw data to distribution and use chi-square

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, fitting

I have a dataset of number of tweets over time similar to this:

```
idx     timestamp    count
1 2015-11-01 08:00:00 2
2 2015-11-01 09:00:00 3
3 2015-11-01 10:00:00 3
4 2015-11-01 11:00:00 0
5 2015-11-01 12:00:00 0
6 2015-11-01 13:00:00 1
7 2015-11-01 14:00:00 0
8 2015-11-01 15:00:00 0
9 2015-11-01 16:00:00 0
10 2015-11-01 17:00:00 3
```

and i'd check what is the best distribution (i.e. between exponential and lognormal) that fits my raw data counts ("count" columns) through R, estimating parameters with MLE. I read a lot of discussions about fitting distributions, but in all cases fitting is done after dividing data in bins and counting the number of elements in each bin . I must instead fit raw counts, and the using a test (chi-square) to verify the goodness of fit. What is the best solution and, then, how can I use chi-square test with 0 values?

UPDATE
A plot example, x-axis is timestamp, y-axis counts.
[image]

Comment: A lognormal is not a serious candidate here for your counts, as it can't be zero and is in any case a continuous distribution. An exponential is also not a natural distribution for counts, as it is continuous. I'd start with a Poisson and see how well that fits. Having counts of 0 is no problem with chi-square as the point is how many counts of 0 you have? (Note that asking for R code is off-topic here.)

Comment: I have 307 0s in a dataset with 1507 values. (updated question with the chart of ts)

Comment: I don't see how the graph bears on your question. But it seems that some process is switched on or begins suddenly. Whether it makes sense to lump the counts together and look for a fit to a brand-name distribution I can't tell.